# Implementing validator contract on existing PoA chain

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis, clique, poa

I'm running a private PoA chain with a height of around 700,000 blocks.

I initialised the chain with two signer addresses included in the genesis file to get things started. Since then we've added further validator nodes through `clique.propose(<address>, true)` but as the chain scales up I'd like to move to having a validator contract similar to those found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts/tree/master/validator_contracts) so we can control signer approval from a central admin point.

Rather than starting a new chain with the validator contract approved to sign from block 0, how can I implement the new contract into the current chain and avoid losing the data we've generated to date?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this question? We're willing to have a smart contract describing the governance rules for sealers - but we cannot seem to find a solution using Geth and we would like to avoid Parity too.